How can i wait until imageCapture to be initialized to take a picture?
How can i wait until the moment imageCapture is initialized, i tried using while (imageCapture == null) {}, but it just crashes the application, using a delay isn't an option too as i want to take a pic with the back cam too, and it would take too long as sometime it can take some time to initialize
Heres my current code
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var imageCapture: ImageCapture? = null
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var outputDirectory: File
    private lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
        supportActionBar?.hide()
        startCamera()
        takePhoto()
        startCameraBack()
        takePhoto()
        outputDirectory = getOutputDirectory()
        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    }
    private fun startCamera() {
        val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
            val cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
            val preview = Preview.Builder().build()
            preview.setSurfaceProvider(findViewById<PreviewView>(R.id.viewFinder).surfaceProvider)
            val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_FRONT_CAMERA
            imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder().build()
            cameraProvider.unbindAll()
            cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture)
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }
    private fun takePhoto() {
        val imageCapture = imageCapture ?: return
        val photoFile = File(
            outputDirectory,
            SimpleDateFormat(FILENAME_FORMAT, Locale.US).format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg"
        )
        val outputOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()
        imageCapture.takePicture(
            outputOptions,
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onError(exc: ImageCaptureException) {
                }
                override fun onImageSaved(output: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    var savedUri: Uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Saved to $savedUri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
    }
    private fun getOutputDirectory(): File {
        val mediaDir = externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull()?.let {
            File(it, resources.getString(R.string.app_name)).apply { mkdirs() }
        }
        return if (mediaDir != null && mediaDir.exists())
            mediaDir else filesDir
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CameraXGFG"
        private const val FILENAME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-SSS"
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cameraExecutor.shutdown()
    }


Your issue comes from cameraProviderFuture.addListener() which is async. Access imageCapture after addListener() was called
